# How can I move an object around the screen by dragging in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

So in my layout I have this ball which I want to drag around the screen. I tried using the onTouch() method, and these are my results:
1)`((Button)findViewById(R.id.ball)).setY(event.getY());`
`((Button)findViewById(R.id.ball)).setX(event.getX());`
This one is very glitchy for some reason. I try to move the ball and it just quickly goes back and forth between two different places.
2) `((Button)findViewById(R.id.ball)).setY(event.getRawY());`
`((Button)findViewById(R.id.ball)).setX(event.getRawX());`
This one works a bit smoother, but when  I start the movement the ball just teleports to some other place. It works fine except for that part where it "teleports"

What I want to achieve:
A normal drag movement of the ball where the ball is right beneath the finger (x and y coordinates of the ball match the x and y coordinates of the touch)

I can add screen recordings explaining the two cases above if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your activity implement `View.OnTouchListener` and import the requested method:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {}
```

Then change newly created `onTouch` method like below:

```
float dX, dY;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
        dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        view.animate()
                .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                .setDuration(0)
                .start();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
return true;
}
```

and finally set this `onTouch` method to your view:

```
ball.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Does this work with objects in fragments as well?